# Python - Double condition data.loc

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-loc

I have the following data frame:

```
Date     Value1   Value2
01-01-01     01       01
02-01-01     02       00
03-01-01     03       01
04-01-01     04      101
```

On this data frame I would like to select just the rows having `Value2==0 and Value2>=100`

For that, I use the following command:

```
data.loc[(data['Value2'] == 0) & (data['Value2'] >= 100)]
```

Which return me an empty DataFrame. I don't really understand why because when I used separately:

```
data.loc[(data['Value2'] == 0)]
```

or:

```
data.loc[(data['Value2'] >= 100)
```

It returns the corrected values.
Does anyone knows how to implement this 2 conditions selection?

Comment: Take a look at your condition. Your value cant be 0 and larger or equal to 100 in the same time ->> empty. Are You maybe trying to do an OR operation? Change & to |.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For you actual input the correct output is empty `DataFrame`. The conditions

```
(data['Value2'] == 0) & (data['Value2'] >= 100)
```

can't be simultaneous *true*. Use `or` operator instead.

```
(data['Value2'] == 0) | (data['Value2'] >= 100)
```

Output

```
    Date     Value1   Value2
02-01-01     02       00
04-01-01     04      101
```

Comment: @ I forgot about the 'or' conditions! Sorry!

Answer (score 1):

I would use the | operator in this example because a value cannot be equal to a specified value AND equal to another. In my example I did not use the .loc function to find the results, and simply used the print function to illustrate the point:

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd

dates = [datetime.datetime(2001, 1, 1), datetime.datetime(2001, 2, 1),   datetime.datetime(2001, 3, 1), datetime.datetime(2001, 4, 1)]
dates_2 = []

for date in dates:
   date = date.strftime('%y-%m-%d')
   dates_2.append(date)

df = pd.DataFrame({'Value1':[01, 02, 03, 04], 'Value2':[01, 00, 01, 101]}, index=dates)

print(df[(df['Value2'] == 0) | (df['Value2'] >= 100)])
```

As you can see above, We use parenthesis to evaluate two conditions as you did, but the difference is that we used the | operator in this example. It's possible that you simply had a logical error. The output is:

```
               Value1  Value2
2001-02-01       2       0
2001-04-01       4     101
```

Obviously using .loc should just return the values for column Value2. I only did a print statement in this example to illustrate the broader point.